# Divide the results of 2 variables from a JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm working on a project where I have a JSON that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        
        "size": 3598,
        "count": 67
    },
    {
        
        "size": 4077,
        "count": 73
    } 
]
```

*The above JSON will have another 1000 size and count pairs in the same file.*
So far I have

```
let sizes = data.map(function (sizes) {
    return sizes.size
  }); 

 let counts = data.map(function (counts) {
    return counts.count
  });
```

These both console.log *a new size and count array from* the JSON. What I want to do next is divide the size by the count and return a new *array* variable called results. Something like below,  however, this returns NaN.

```
let results = (sizes / counts) 
  console.log(results);
```

*//intended results array: [ {53.70149253731343}, {55.84931506849315‬} ...]*

Comment: Could you provide example output?

Comment: I have added an intended results array to the end of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with just one `map` step:

```
let results = data.map(({size, count}) => size / count);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns an array. From docs,

> The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of
> calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

You should use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
let data = [{"size": 3598,"count": 67},{"size": 4077,"count": 73}];

let sizes = data.reduce(function (a, c) {
  return a + c.size
}, 0); 

let counts = data.reduce(function (a, c) {
  return a + c.count
}, 0);

let results = (sizes / counts) 
  console.log(results);
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, however, I didn't ask the question properly. I have added an edit with intended results.